# CPU settings stuck on AUTO in BIOS after BIOS update

Tags: memory, cpu, motherboard, bios, overclocking

I've just updated my BIO on my motherboard ( MSI z170a gaming m5) to the last version and, in my “OC Settings Menu,” CPU ratio and Ring ratio are stuck on AUTO.

Before that update I was stable on my own overclock profile and I’d make the change (CPU ratio - Ring ratio - Voltage ) every time I needed by entering BIOS config or from other software app such as “Intel extreme utility.”

But now I’ve updated the BIOS and the CPU (i5- 6600k) is stuck on 0.80ghz.
No possibilities to change it manually with the except of disabling 'Intel adaptive thermal monitor' from CPU features.

In this case, CPU ratio increases to a max of 3.5ghz but is still stuck on AUTO if I want to change it manually.

Same issue trying to change it from Software apps.

Further, checking CPU ratio from the latter and not from Bios result that it is working on 3.9ghz.

- (Profile 2 boosts my RAM to 2666mhz)

Last I’ve tried to switch on GameBoost mode but it only increase CPU to 4.1ghz and decrease RAM speed to 2400mhz

[image: Bios_Problem]

Comment: I would downgrade your firmware unless the update specifically resolved a problem you were trying to resolve.  This will confirm if your inability to change the setting is due to the new firmware or due to a default behavior which can be changed.

Comment: @Ramhound Nice advice. i've just tried 5 other version of it but nothing changes. if it helps, i had same 0.80ghz problem 2 years ago with the previous firmware but i don't remember how i solved it

Comment: You failed to mention you have had this problem before.  Which indicates the problem has nothing to do with the firmware being updated, but your settings being reset, you will have to determine which settings must be enabled/disabled to accomplish what you want.  Difficult for anyone else to play around with the settings unless they have exactly the same firmware.

Comment: @Ramhound i don't know if it is a firmware problem. i've just explained what happened. if you read carefully you'll understand that it is not the same problem i had before. This time the CPU stucked at 3.5, something that hasn't happened last time. For sure two years ago i solved enablig/disabling "intel c-state", but this time doesn't work

Comment: "I had same 0.80ghz problem 2 years ago" - You said it was the same problem.  Your screenshot is extremely busy.  However, you have confirmed it isn't the firmware that is causing it since you downgraded and you still have the same problem.  You have restored the defaults I assume?

Comment: yes only the same 0.80ghz problem, it was never stucked at 3.5ghz before. Yes i've restored the defaults. What do you suggest? what's wrong with my screenshots?

Answer (score 0):

I pressed ENTER on the CPU Ratio and had to press SHIFT + to raise the number and sometimes it wouldn't go so I would press SHIFT - until it reset to 4200 then I could raise it. However, I could only get it to 4500 max.